# How can I accept an argument list in a constructor and add it to a collection in Java?

Tags: java, list, collections, constructor

I'm trying to make a constructor that would accept any number of variables of class "Item" as a variable argument list and add them to appropriate collection. What would be the best way to go about it?

My code so far:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Order {

    private static long counter;
    private final long orderNumber;
    private final List<Item> items;

    public Order(long counter, long orderNumber, Item... args) {
        this.counter = counter;
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;

        items{
           list.add(Item);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a problem with this? the `Item... args` should suffice, no?

Comment: What is counter? If you’re trying to count how many orders there are, this won’t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Item... args` should be fine.. You can then just do this

```
this.items = Arrays.asList(args);
```

… instead of the static `items` block.

See similar [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/92US8p).

Comment: maybe also `Arrays.asList(args)`

Comment: when the list (items) needs to change in the future, this is not the best solution, as Arrays.asList(args) returns a fixed-length array (which throw an unsupportedoperationexception  when applied with add and delete operations).

Comment: @Arthurofos you think that's a problem in the current context? you think he will use the constructor and then extend it? I mean you're right, but....what do you suggest?

Comment: he can use new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(args)); instead of Arrays.asList(args); or Stream.of(args).collect(Collectors.toList())

Comment: Arrays.asList : will make your collection You can't add to it; you can't remove from it. You can't structurally modify the List.

Comment: @Hamza If a resizable `List` is later needed, simply pass the fixed-size list to the constructor of a suitable implementation of `List`, like this: `List<Item> resizableList = new ArrayList<>( fixedSizeArray ) ;` Generally speaking, immutability-by-default is best, until determining an actual need for mutability. So I would use [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)): `this.items = List.of( args );`